# Firebase Cloud Function - Fetch all docs matching current Timestamp

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am running a scheduled cloud function that executes every 60 seconds. Within this function I am trying to fetch all the docs that have a value 'remindAt' matching current Timestamp.now().

After these have been fetched I would like to perform another function; for now it is just updating a value within the doc, however later on it will be sending a notification to the users device...

In the Google Cloud log console I am not receiving any errors, however, nothing seems to be updating in Firestone and I have noticed I am getting some random spikes of read/write documents. Even if the code was working it should not be more than 2 or 3 read/writes at the moment.

Please see node.js code below & screenshot of firebase console.

This is my first time working with firebase cloud functions etc, so most likely my code is not the best... I'd appreciate any assistance!

```
const timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

exports.checkReminders = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun((context) => {

      const reminderRef = database.collection("Reminders");
      reminderRef.where("remindAt", "==", timestamp).get().then((snapshot) => {

        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref.update({"completed": true});
          console.log("Updated completed to True");
        });
      });
  });
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

So I have managed to solve my issues above.

**Issue 1, random spikes:** This was caused from me opening Firebase Cloud Firestore Data... Basically opening/leaving the web page multiple times started to create a spike in read data...

The code I have change it to the following:
Basically I have created a cloud function to check the Reminder collection every 60 seconds for any documents that have a reminder at less than or equal to the current time .now() and if so it sets completed to true (this is so it cannot be called again in the future.)

```
    exports.checkReminders = functions.pubsub
        .schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async (context) => {
          const query = await database.collection("Reminders")
              .where("remindAt", "<=", admin.firestore.Timestamp.now())
              .where("completed", "==", false).get();
    
          query.forEach(async (snapshot) => { 

// Here you can call another function which sends the notification to a specific device.

            await database.doc("Reminders/" + snapshot.id).update({
              "completed": true, 
            });
          });
        });
```